# WHY does this assembly code issue segmentation fault warning?

Tags: assembly, exploit

The code that I am struggling with is shown below:

```
section .text
global _start
_start:
        xor eax, eax
        push eax
        push 0x68732f2f  ;This is equivalent to push '//sh'
        push 0x6e68622f  ;This is equivalent to push '/bin'
        mov ebx, esp
        push eax
        push ebx
        mov ecx, esp
        xor edx, edx
        mov al, 0x0b
        int 0x80

        mov eax, 0x01
        xor ebx, ebx
        int 0x80
```

Basically, what this code supposedly does is that it slips some null-terminated string "/bin/sh" into the memory (specifically, the top of the stack), along with a char *[2], which holds the address of the aforementioned string and a null character, then it invokes system call execve() to spawn a shell.

The problem I am facing is that after I compiled and linked it by typing "nasm -f elf code.asm" and "ld -m elf_i386 -o code code.o", it did not seem to work properly.

In case it matters, the linux distribution I am running is 64-bit Ubuntu version 14.04.

Hope that you guys could help me out here. Sincere thanks in advance!

Comment: `0x68` is `h` not `i`. You want `0x69`.

Comment: @WoodrowDouglass they are in the correct order, exactly because stack grows down.

Comment: @Jester you're right, mybad. Sorry.

Comment: @icbytes that's not relevant here. Nothing is executed from the stack, only the parameters are set up there. **The code is fine** except for the typo.

Comment: Jup, I see it, was too quick, the stack is not altered, once filled, only pushes are done, I deleted my hint,

Comment: Why do you push 4B of zeros, since you have room for a zero-byte in 8 bytes of immediate data?  `/bin/sh\0` is 8B, so you could just do that and drop the `//` padding.  Also, did you try just running your code under `strace`?  That would probably show `execve` returning with an error, and show you the args.  Then you'd figure out that it crashed because it continued executing after your code corrupted the stack.

Comment: @Jester Apologies for my carelessness. The code worked fine as I just tried after correcting 0x68 to 0x69. Thanks for your help.